# node.js classic example strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

there is classic node example:

```
var http = require('http');
var s = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
    res.write('hi there\n');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.end('and here');
    },2000);
});
s.listen(8000);
```

and when i run

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

its going fine, "hi there" and over 2 sec - "and here". ok.

but when i change the string#4 and remove \n:

```
 res.write('hi there');
```

i see delay (2sec) and **simultaneously** output without any timeout between "hi there" and "and here"

node -v = 4.2.6

this is good, this is bad or this is unimportant?

Comment: What about the comment in http module: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L618

Comment: Looks like a line-wise buffer to me.

Comment: @Risto Novik, thanx. but this comment, unfortunately, it is not quite clear to me.  As i understood,   "\n" in request may prevent this request to be sending in socket. But i talk about simple responce `res.write('...');`, which not immediately output without '\n'.

Comment: @Bergi, thanx. what is line-wise buffer?

Comment: @d2048 A buffer that flushes when it sees a line terminator

Comment: @Bergi, so this is a bug or a feature in my case?

Comment: @d2048: Buffering in general is necessary for larger packet sizes, which reduce overhead - feature - but in your case not flushing for 2s is a bit long - bug. Only we don't know where in the line it occurs; it could easily be the terminal that you're runnig `curl` in and have nothing to do with `node`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be browser specific behavior. firefox shows the data  immediately while chrome seems to buffer and wait until the response is ended.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is in the comments: `it's a line-wise buffer, a buffer that flushes when it sees a line terminator.`